# Angles in cosmology

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

We have several definitions of distances in cosmology. Take angular diameter distance.  $$d_A = a(t)\int \frac{dt}{a(t)}\;.$$ If an object has proper length $L$ then the angle $\theta$ it is seen at is

$$\theta = \frac{L}{d_A}$$
This is similar to the way an angle $\theta$ and arc length $s$ are related in a circle with radius $r$
$$ \theta = \frac{s}{r}$$
On cosmological scales distances are so vast that the arc length $s$ is indistinguishable from the proper length $L$ of the star or galaxy observed. All this is fine. But when it comes to the cosmic microwave background, we look at temperature correlations between two directions $\vec{n_1}$ and $\vec{n_2}$ with an angle $\theta$ between them on the sky today. 
$$ C(\theta) = C(\vec{n_1}\cdot\vec{n_2})$$

These angles are not small necessarily. For the quadrupole there is $90$ degrees between the two directions. Subsequent Higher multipoles have smaller angles. With such wide angles we should no longer use
$$\theta = \frac{L}{d_A}$$
but instead use 
$$tan(\theta) = \frac{L}{d_A}$$
Where am I going wrong with this line of thought?

Comment: If I may make a suggestion to think about, when you consider angles like pi/2 across the CMB, L is no longer the proper length. In fact, across such scales, proper length has no meaning. Also, since we can approximate all parts of the CMB as being at roughly the same distance away, that does imply that the distances are a type of arc length. Consider that if $\theta=\pi /2$, then L must be an arc length (or close  to it) otherwise the midpoint of the object would be about 0.707 times as far. But like I said, at that point, proper distances are fairly meaningless